# How to convert hours to work days, with different working times a day?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this problem. I am doing a gantt chart, and I need to convert hours to days.
The problem is, that from Monday to Thursday, the working period is 9 hours and on Friday is 4 hours.

I can not figure it out, how to do this.
I managed to get hours from days, but not on the contrary.
The formula i used to get the hours:

```
=SUMIF(I10:AQ10;1;$I$6:$AQ$6)
```

I placed 1 or 0 in the chart to mark the working days.

I am from Czech republic so sorry for the names.
Hodiny means hours,
Pracovní dny means working days,
Po,út... are days

[image]

Comment: Divide by 24, there are 24 hours in a day. Not sure what else you need.

Comment: I know that there are 24 hours in a day. But i need if I have for example 40 hours, to make it like 5 days a week not 2 days. If you know what I mean.  Like for monday only 9 hours, tuesday same... etc and for friday only 4 hours. I am not good at explaining in other language than Czech.

Comment: So if the working day is 8 hours, then 40 / 8 = 5.

Comment: I dont know if I am so bad at explaining. If that was this simple like 8 hours a day, I wouldnt asking this question here. From monday to thursday is 9 hours of work a day and on Friday is only 4 hours that makes 40 hours a week. But its not 8 hours everyday.

Comment: So test to see if the day is any of Monday to Thursday and divide by 9, if Friday divide by 4. IF() may be3 useful. Of course if the amount exceeds 40 then you will have overtime...

Comment: I have no idea how to do the formula with dividing like that. Maybe i was thinking about substraction from whole hours, but no clue either.

Comment: Not sure you need to convert hours to work day. I think [COUNTIFS formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) should meet your needs. Try `=COUNTIFS(I10:AQ10;1;$I$6:$AQ$6;"<>0")`. It counts the number of days (marked with 1) for which working period isn't 0. EDIT, even `=COUNTIF(I10:AQ10;1)` could meet your needs.

Comment: I need convert hours to work day. Because I am working with hours first, not days. I was trying COUNTIFS formula too, but its not what i need.  The 1 or 0 depends on the number of day i set. And the end date works with the day too. I just need convert the hours with that specific working hours a day 9 and 4. To be more clear, for inspiration on this gantt chart i watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un8j6QqpYa0&ab_channel=Vertex42. And I added hours to it, and i need the chart to work with hours or just the hours convert to days and it will work the same.

Comment: @Simon, to understand correctly, you need to count number of days based on the number of hours worked (which is 18 in your exemple) and knowing that 4 days of week is 9 hours and 1 day is 4 hours ?

Comment: Can the number of hours be more than 40? Would it go into a second week if the number of hours was 50?

Comment: Yes it will, I just need convert the hours into days.

Comment: The problem is that it isnt a converting issue. In order to "convert" work hours into work days you need to know (a least) the number of 9 work hours-work day or number of 4 work hours-work day.

Comment: Then divide by 40 to get the number of weeks, divide the remainder by 9 to get the number of days. Will post an answer later unless anyone else does. If there is a variation in the work pattern from 9+9+9+9+4, it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment it isnt a converting problem. You could use euclidian division to find a solution but it could be wrong.
Here is my solution (and i guess @Tom Sharpe's too) :

`=5*QUOTIENT(A1;40)+QUOTIENT(MOD(A1;40);9)+QUOTIENT(MOD(MOD(A1;40);9);4)` (A1 being the cell where you store work hours)

Basically, it counts the number of full work week (40 hours) and multiply it by 5 (work day in a week) then, which the remaining hours counts the number of 9 work hours-day and then, with the remaining hours counts the number 4 work hours-day.

It only works if most weeks are composed of 4x9 hours days + 1x4 hours days. For exemple, if for some reasons you only work on friday for 10 weeks (so 10 days), this formula will only display 5 work days. Hope that this was clear.

EDIT : To count a day when total work hours represent some days + some hours (less than a day)

`=5*QUOTIENT(A1;40)+QUOTIENT(MOD(A1;40);9)+QUOTIENT(MOD(MOD(A1;40);9);4)+IF(MOD(MOD(MOD(A1;40);9);4)<>0;1;0))`

Comment: Thank you, that seems like its working.  I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Already done it.

Comment: Yup, that would have been my answer too but credit to you for a nice formula. If you wanted to take it further with a variation in work hours per day you might end up using Scan to work out a running total of hours and find where that matched a certain number of days but that seems too elaborate for the current problem.

Comment: I know I took your answer as solution for my problem. But the Scan function got my attention. I tried something, but I still dont understand how it works. I tried substracting the hours from total hours, and I figured out that if the last number is greater than -9 it works even better than your solution. Dont get me wrong, your solution is great, but if I have 100 hours its only 12 days, but 2 hours are in 13th day... if you know what I mean, and I would like to end on 13th day not 12th. So maybe if its possible to change somehow your formula or use Scan function. If not, its not a big deal.

Comment: Hi, no worries ! I am unfamiliar with `Scan` too, but curious to understand how it works. Maybe @TomSharpe , could be willing to give us hint ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well this is what I was thinking. If you had an irregular work pattern and still wanted to find how many days had been worked (counting any part days left over at the end as an extra day), you could work out a running total using scan and use match to find how many days that was equal to. There are two cases:

(1) where it's an exact number of days, e.g. the number of hours is 9, 18 etc.

(2) where it's not an exact number of days, e.g. the number of hours is 10, 20 etc.

But then you have to ignore the days with zero hours (like weekends).

```
=LET(range,I$6:R$6,
hours,G11,
runningTotal,SCAN(0,range,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
lastDay,IFERROR(MATCH(hours,runningTotal,0),MATCH(hours,runningTotal,1)+1),
COUNTIF(INDEX(range,1):INDEX(range,lastDay),">0"))
```

[image]

*EDIT*

For the case where hours is less than the hours on the first day,

```
=LET(range,I$6:R$6,
hours,G11,
runningTotal,SCAN(0,range,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
lastDay,IF(hours<INDEX(range,1),1,IFERROR(MATCH(hours,runningTotal,0),MATCH(hours,runningTotal,1)+1)),
COUNTIF(INDEX(range,1):INDEX(range,lastDay),">0"))
```

*EDIT 2*

For the case when hours is blank or zero:

```
=LET(range,I$6:R$6,
hours,G11,
runningTotal,SCAN(0,range,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
lastDay,IF(hours<INDEX(range,1),1,IFERROR(MATCH(hours,runningTotal,0),MATCH(hours,runningTotal,1)+1)),
IFS(hours="","",hours=0,0,TRUE,COUNTIF(INDEX(range,1):INDEX(range,lastDay),">0")*(hours>0)))
```

Comment: If you had less than 9 hours, this would produce an error, so you'd have to handle that as a special case if it could ever occur.

Comment: And thats the problem. Its possible, that sometimes it will be less than 9 hours. I am not good at complicated formulas, so how can I treat this case ? I am sorry for bothering you with this, but I want it to work the best.

Comment: Have added to my answer.

Comment: Now this works very well. Just one more thing I need to ask. Why is it not working above 360 hours ?

Comment: Oh my bad. I figured out. My max range of weeks was just for 360 hours. Now this works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: That's great, I thought it was to do with the range but didn't have time to check. The only other thing I can think of is to add a check for hours=0 or blank in case there are any blanks or zeroes

Comment: Your solution have problem with the range, thats expected. Because iam changing the data with slider in that range. I dont have like whole chart, i have just part of it. Its working like in the video i sent i took inspiration from it. So the range never changes but the data do. And thats problem if I need chart which containing whole year of work, it will just not work. But @Thomas C. edited his version and that suits better for this. But both solutions are great. And I must thank both of you for your time and effort. 
If I will have any further questions, I will contact you here.